# Where is the best place to schedule AlarmManager to do a periodic background data sync?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My Android application will be periodically polling a server to check for data.  I want this polling to happen regardless of user interaction with the application, similar (in concept) to how the Gmail and Google Reader apps sync data in the background.  Once the app is installed, these periodic syncs should begin happening.  I do **not** think that scheduling the alarm from inside an `Activity` is the way to go, because I do not want to wait for the user to open my application.

**What is the best practice in this case for placing the call to** `AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating`?

Some possibilities I could think of are:

- Extend `Application` and do it in `onCreate`
- Do the scheduling from within a `Service` that is set to `android:enabled=true` within the manifest.
- Listen for some particular broadcast message(s), and schedule from within a receiver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a on boot receiver and use it to start a service that schedules the alarm.  Check out this link: http://www.thetekblog.com/?p=77

Comment: This seems like one piece of the puzzle, but wouldn't that only get broadcasted when the device reboots? I want the alarm to be scheduled right after the app is installed.

Comment: @elevine: On first run of your app, also set up the alarm schedule.

Comment: @CommonsWare where in my app do you think I should do that?  Extend Application and do it in onCreate?

Comment: @elevine: Possibly. You presumably have an activity in the launcher -- you could also do it there, saving you the hassle of a custom `Application` (if you're not using that for anything else).

Comment: @elevine: "I want the alarm to be scheduled right after the app is installed." -- fortunately, that is impossible.

Comment: @CommonsWare The app is going to act as middleware, so there is not much need for direct user interaction.  However, if there is no other option then I'll have them open an initial Activity after install.

Comment: Quite correct - getting code to run after an application is installed without user interaction is impossible. So on installation, you need to make sure the user opens your application atleast once. After that, the boot completed broadcast is enough.

Answer (score 0):

"Do the scheduling from within a Service that is set to android:enabled=true within the manifest."

A service is enabled by default - but that doesn't mean anything would start it automatically. The only reason a service would be disabled in configuration is if you have some code somewhere that enables it programmatically.